Brushing pastries with jam
I've made these apricot pastries using puff pastry, pastry cream and tinned apricot halves, using this recipe:

I know they would be better served fresh from the oven, but that's not an option in this case, I need to serve them tomorrow. Am I better off brushing with apricot jam now, or waiting until just before I serve them to do this?

I know what I'm going to try baking this weekend....   That looks delicious !

The “brush with jam” is called nappage in kitchen lingo and serves to create a protective layer on your baked items (plus makes it shine and can glue on nuts or other decorations).
Traditionally, it’s applied hot on pastry straight from the oven, so you would complete the step now, even if you plan to store the pastries for a while. Let them set and dry well, and be a bit careful in case you need to stack them, adding parchment in between can be a good idea.

Thank you! That's what I ended up doing so hopefully they'll taste good today :)

And given the rate at which they disappeared, it's safe to say they did still taste good :)

Note that it's better to do this when the pastries are hot because the jam will "melt" somewhat from the heat of the pastry and form a more uniform layer than if it was applied to a cold pastry.
